# Why the QTableView is painted black when i resize the Dialog?

Tags: qt, qtableview, qdialog, qtsql

I have a problem when the resize function, I do this in the click signal:

```
if(ShowingDetails){
    ui->BtShowingData->setText("<< Hide details");
    //this->setMaximumWidth(1050);
    //this->setMinimumWidth(1050);
    this->resize(1050, height());
}else {
    ui->BtShowingData->setText("Show details >>");
    //this->setMaximumWidth(750);
    //this->setMinimumWidth(750);
    this->resize(750, height());
}
```

The resize method does its work, but I have two QTableView (with filtering) and when the windows grows up, the  Tables are painted black, if I click on them, return to normal. I used `ui->TbViewDatosNewAlum->repaint();` but nothing happend. If I update the `QSqlTableModel`, it's not painted black, but I can't do this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please, anybody can help me? i don't know how to fix this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found a temporary solution. Hope this helps

Before doing resizing job hide the QTableWidget or QTableView:

```
tableWidget->hide();
```

After finishing resizing, show the QTableWidget or QTableView:

```
tableWidget->show();
```

It may cause flickering in old systems........but I don't think any system is that old. :)

Comment: To format code, just make sure you have a blank line before it, and indent all code at least 4 spaces. You can also use the `{ }` icon in the editor to indent many lines at once.